# How to bind a Richfaces 'oncomplete' event with jQuery?

Tags: richfaces, jquery

I am trying to bind an jQuery function to an 'oncomplete' event on a Richfaces 3.3 a4j:commandButton component.
Since I dont want to place the function on the commandButton component itself, I am trying to bind it on document load. 
I think though that the event does not get bound on document load due since the button is not rendered yet?

Heres how I placed the binding...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#Btn1').bind('complete', function(){                    
                jQuery('#panel1').slideUp(750);
                jQuery('.selection1').slideDown(750);
                jQuery('.Next1').show();
            }); });
```

Here is the command button, which is in another page include that is reused in multiple places. This is the reason why I dont want to place this one function on the button itself.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="Btn1" value="Select"/>
```

So how would I bind an 'oncomplete' function to the Btn1 component from another location, say a parent page?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Richfaces 4 But I think the same theory applies.

You are not attaching the event to the commandbutton per se, but to the ajax event that is created by clicking the button (assuming onclick returns true)

In actuality it is some magic that JSF will perform that if that component triggers an action it will call that JS when the ajax is rendered.

There is nothing per se done before the click, it is realistically a server side attribute.

Richfaces (4 at least) extends the regular JSF ajax (javascript) object and I believe you can attach your handler to that. But that may not be of any real help to you. I had to attach a handler to it to fix some viewstate issues.

you can always attach a function to the oncomplete on the button that references a not necessarily existent function.

so  `<a4j:commandButton ... oncomplete="foo()"/>`

and then on any page that includes that button include you could define that function. Not the nicest solution but may be your best bet.